# javascript variables and functions with arrays for each html formel

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

is it possible to reuse this javascript

```
<script>
var speed = 100;
var gold = 0;
gold = parseFloat(gold.toFixed(2));
var production = 10;
production = parseFloat(production.toFixed(0));
var price = 100;
price = parseFloat(price.toFixed(2));
document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
document.getElementById("production").innerHTML=production;
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price;
function dig() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("bar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, speed);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      elem.style.width = '0%';
      gold = gold + production;
      gold = parseFloat(gold.toFixed(2));
      document.getElementById("dig").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
      if (price <= gold) {
            document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = true;
        }
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("dig").disabled = true;
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function priceUpgrade() {
    if (price <= gold) {
        document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = true;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function upgrade(){
    $("#upgrade").click(function(){
        speed = speed - 10;
        gold = gold - price;
        gold = parseFloat(gold.toFixed(2));
        production += production * 0.10;
        production = parseFloat(production.toFixed(0));
        price += price * 0.50;
        price = parseFloat(price.toFixed(2));
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
        document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML=gold;
        document.getElementById("production").innerHTML=production;
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price;
        if (price <= gold) {
            document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("upgrade").disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

with a new value in the variables speed, gold and production for each new html line of these

```
<div id="speed">100</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div id="production"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="dig()" id="dig">Gull Sil</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div id="progress">
      <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="price"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="upgrade()" id="upgrade">Oppgrader</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

so each time a call speed[3] or dig(3) both the variables and the functions response different to each key=>value in an array or some how??
maybe var speed {1:10,2:30,3:70,4:150};
and dig([1,2,3,4]);

Comment: i needed to shorten my decimals, but that does answer my guestion??

Comment: @nina Scholz do you have a solution to shorten the float function, so i dont get 10 decimals??

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ID inside the same document. So, if I'm getting your question right you should first change your markup to use classes. ...It's not clear whether you're also planning to use multiple forms (*formel???*) or what...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i am new to javascript, so should i make these classes and dublicated ids?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please give me an empty answer and i will give you an approvel for your answer..

Comment: Hi Nicolai. Still today after re-reading (a bit tired) your question I'm still not absolutely positive about what you're trying to achieve... *`"some how??"`* is the only thing I understand :) Nothing else. Please read [ask]. I'd suggest to be more concise, explain what's currently happening, explain throughout your issue but in a couple of paragraphs - and explain what you're after and the expected result. Thank you

Comment: @roko  I accepted your first answer with no duplicates, will you  write it as an answer, so i can approve it

Comment: Kind of you. Please, feel free to delete the question. If you think the answer was specific and could help future visitors, you're welcome to provide an Answer to your own question. If all it was were duplicated IDs I'd just delete the question - considering it a minor bug.